# Best high order function to use on this array to a return a bool value if "submit_instance_key" has a value of 1?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, reduce

I'm looking for the best high order function to use on this array of arrays to return a bool if there is a `submit_instance_key` value of 1.

I've looked into using a `filter` and `reduce` but I'm having trouble dealing with the nested arrays. I've also tried to `compactMap` it but it changes the shape of the array.

```
var someArray = [["submit_instance_key": 0, "instance_id_key": 4], ["submit_instance_key": 0, "instance_id_key": 4], ["submit_instance_key": 1, "instance_id_key": 5]]
```

I'm hoping to return a Bool if there is a `submit_instance_key` value of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best high level function to use is one that stops searching as soon as it finds a match.  [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) is a good function to use for this purpose.  It takes a closure that gets applied to each element of the array in turn and stops as soon as it finds an element that returns `true`.

```
var someArray = [["submit_instance_key": 0, "instance_id_key": 4], ["submit_instance_key": 0, "instance_id_key": 4], ["submit_instance_key": 1, "instance_id_key": 5]]

let found = someArray.contains(where: { $0["submit_instance_key"] == 1 })
print(found)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> true
> ```